# Why is “It isn’t her” incorrect?

Tags: grammar

Reading *The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe* by C. S. Lewis, this happens (p 115 of my edition):

> “It’s all right,” he was shouting. “Come out, Sons and Daughters of Adam. It’s all right! It isn’t *Her*!” This was bad grammar of course, but that is how beavers talk when they are excited […]

Where is the bad grammar there? I think “It isn’t her” sounds fine (to my American ears), with “her” being the object and “it” being the subject. Is there a grammar rule I’m not aware of that would make “she” more correct? Is the bad grammar elsewhere?

Comment: You've cut out a few words: “It’s all right,” he was shouting. “**Come out, Mrs. Beaver**. Come out, Sons and Daughters of Adam **and Eve**. It’s all right! It isn’t *Her*!”

Comment: @Justin I can't help but think it might be a matter of version differences. The ["adult" version](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZiYU9NS4QkYC&pg=PA158&dq=%22come+out+Sons+and+Daughters+of+Adam%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&gbmsitb=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiK4sLr5vz2AhXKGTQIHXDsCbwQuwV6BAgCEAc#v=onepage&q=%22come%20out%20Sons%20and%20Daughters%20of%20Adam%22&f=false) doesn't have "and Eve", for example.

Comment: @Laurel: Ah, sorry. I was familiar with the "and Eve" version. In fact, the [1950 version](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=sFNniYvWRAAC&q=%22come+out,+Sons+and+Daughters+of+Adam%22&dq=%22come+out,+Sons+and+Daughters+of+Adam%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjYyeLW6fz2AhUr7XMBHRi4COMQ6AF6BAgCEAI) didn't have "and Eve".

Comment: A point to bear in mind is that Lewis was a professor of English in England. Not America. You should hear everyone in Narnia talking RP.

Comment: @Justin This was specifically the 2005 edition published after the movie came out. I wasn't aware there were multiple texts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Chronicles of Narnia were published in the 1950s, when the standard was to use the nominative case in such situations. “It is she” rather than “It is her.”

Forms of “to be” don’t take an object, but rather a complement.

But today it’s conventional to say “It’s me,” “It’s her,” “It’s them.”

Comment: A quick look at google ngram shows the two forms "It is her/she" running in variable but almost equal use for the last 200 years. I see no problem with either.

Comment: NGrams are fine but won't tell you what CS Lewis thought was the correct version. It would be useful to search his works to see which he prefers in other places.

Comment: @Anton But 'But today it’s conventional to say ...“It’s her" ...'. And the Google ngrams carry about 80% false positives (estimate from a quick look): ('It is her fault' / '... it is. She ...' etc).

Comment: It's a comment by Lewis on the state of flux in English. 'This was bad grammar of course, but that is how beavers talk when they are excited.' It's interesting that Geoff Pullum would apparently let beavers into his home, but not C S Lewis (at least the 50s C S Lewis).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You are right: I agree that "It's her" is almost universal in what I read and hear. Ngram despite its faults at least points to enough usage that we need not worry about the ungrammaticality of either.

Comment: @Anton I think I read somewhere that the default case after the copula was the accusative until some historical big?wig got hold of things and said it was uneducated and illogical not to follow the Latin pattern. Loudly.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — This is quite interesting in its own right. To hell with Google ngrams. What does Shakespeare say, or Chaucer? I would imagine there must have been a question on this previously (several, no doubt — but one with researched historical answers), but if not, it should be asked.

Comment: Nothing has changed since 1950. Prescriptivist drivel started long before that. Lewis is gently sending up this silly "rule" that people were often taught at school. Just about everything they ever learned about grammar, as it goes.

Comment: Lewis was a moralist, not a linguist. Tolkien knew better, but Lewis didn't.